Azure DevOps pipleine fails for Android app: Could not find com.shopify:livedata-ktx:2.0.2
I have an app hostend on Azure DevOps nad a pipeline set up. It has worked perfectly for a year - every merge to master builds .aab and propagates it to AppCenter and PlayStore.
This is the Gradle YAML:
variables:
  wrapperScript: 'gradlew'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: 'gradlew bundleRelease bundleStaging bundleDev'
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Parameters.wrapperScript)'
    options: ' -x lint -s --stacktrace'
    tasks: 'bundleRelease bundleStaging bundleDev'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0

Without changing any configuration, it started giving this error:


in app's configuration build.gradle(:app) I have:
implementation 'com.shopify:livedata-ktx:2.0.2'

wheares in the project build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.21'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.50'
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

This library is used in legacy code and I can resolve the issue by deleting it and cherry-picking the few methods that are used, but I want to figure out why is this happening.
Note: needless to say it builds locally (I've cleaned cache in AS to see if I can recreate the failure, but nohing has happened) with no issues.
Any ideas, what am I not seeing/missing?

Hi ViksaaSkool, when you say ‘Without changing any configuration’ do you mean that the configuration of the pipeline has not changed, but the source code has? If so, can you try to build the previous successfully built version of the code to see if the same error occurs?
If neither the pipeline configuration nor the source code has changed, please compare the previous successful pipeline logs to see if there are any version changes, such as agent version, task version and some software version.

If you are using Microsoft hosted agent, please try to create a self-hosted agent on your local successfully built machine to see if the same error occurs. The above steps can help narrow down the issue.   By the way, you can enable the system.debug to check if there are more details in the debug log.

Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try to see if any of these can help in debugging.

Hi ViksaaSkool, hope you can find some success in debugging, and update the issue. Good luck to you!
